# Objective-C getValue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have defined a class, POI.h:

```
@interface POI : NSObject
```

which is just a simple class that that has certain properties and a method defined as follows:

```
- (NSString *) getValue:(NSString *)key;
```

In my controller, when I try to log invocation of that method:

```
  NSLog(@"Name: %@", [poi getValue:@"name"]);
```

I get

> Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 error Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code **254**

Based on some previous SO answers, I figured out that error 254 when trying to log a return value from a void method. So I came to conclusion that the method my compiler is trying to invoke is actually

```
- (void)getValue:(void *)value;
```

defined in `NSValue.h`, which is of void type.

Now, I would really like to understand WHY this happens. Is my improper and foolish naming of the getValue method the only reason?
How can I avoid it?

Actual error message:

> LBSViewController.mm
>
> 1. parser at end of file
> 2. Code generation
> 3. Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module '/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/project1/Classes/LBSViewController.mm'.
> 4. Running pass 'ARM Instruction Selection' on function '`@"\01-[LBSViewController initializeLBS]"`'
>
> clang: error: unable to
>   execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
>   clang: error: clang frontend
>   command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
>   Apple LLVM
>   version 4.2 (clang-425.0.27) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
>   Target:
>   arm-apple-darwin12.5.0
>   Thread model: posix
>   clang: note: diagnostic
>   msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to
>   http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash
>   backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
>   clang:
>   note: diagnostic msg:
>
> ---
>
> PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
>   Preprocessed
>   source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
>   clang: note:
>   diagnostic msg:
>   /var/folders/y_/h89vdcjj7zs8s5zjh77x4h0h0000gn/T/LBSViewController-A4zhXy.mm
>   clang: note: diagnostic msg:
>   /var/folders/y_/h89vdcjj7zs8s5zjh77x4h0h0000gn/T/LBSViewController-A4zhXy.sh
>   clang: note: diagnostic msg:

Comment: Please post the actual error message from the compiler, not the summary.

Comment: you shouldn't call you method name getSomething. It's - (id)something; and -(void)setSomething:(id)something;

Comment: it is like half the page and you won't know much more from it.

Comment: `getValue:` is a KVC keyword, please chooose some other name and try again.

Comment: But it holds the secret to the solution.  You cannot continue without it.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I was willing to say the same

Comment: @NicolasManzini: So posted it as answer :p

Comment: OK the error message shows that the compiler is crashing.  There is nothing more to say about that, apart from update to a later version.

Comment: I told you I won't shed much light :D

Comment: I don't understand why you posted a question here.  Compiler crashes are very rare and cannot be easily worked-around.

Comment: To support @AnoopVaidya's comment, read Apple's KVC docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html

Comment: NSLog line is causing a crash. I don't know how to state it more clear than that. If I remove NSLog method, everything compiles fine. It is happening because "getValue" is being recognized as a void method, instead of a NSString* one. The question is WHY, is it only because of KVC or is there another reason.

Comment: @Maggie **clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11** This is a compiler crash.  End of story.   If removing that line of code causes the compiler to not crash, then that line has some set of invisible or non-ASCII characters that the compiler is tripping over.  Unless the compiler crash is happening such that your executable is still being produced, your code isn't even being run.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a compiler crash and has nothing to do with how that code is written or how it might behave at runtime.

Follow the instructions and file a bug.

More likely than not, the crash is caused by either a garbage character in just the wrong spot or, even more likely, your syntax is so hosed somewhere else that it is causing the compiler to become unhinged.

Post the code for your `initializeLBS` method as that is what is triggering the crash (according to the compiler's error message).

---

Note that methods should not be prefixed with `get`.  Won't cause the compiler to crash, but it is bad form.

See Key-Value Coding and NSDictionary for similar API patterns that you would likely want to follow.

Comment: NSLog method is triggering the crash, once I remove it, everything runs fine.

Comment: @Maggie Yes, according to your error, it is a compiler crash.  If removing that line fixes it, then that line has bogus characters.   Are there any other warnings/errors generated by your project?

Comment: Nothing related to the current class

Comment: @Maggie Put it back in the state where the compiler crashes, then file a bug , please, using the instructions provided in the error.  Post the bug # here and I'll follow up.

Answer (score -3):

You question, is this because of the naming, yes it is. In both cases the selector to call boils down to:
getValue:

There is no parameter type info at this level and no return type info. You're not allowed to overload functions based on parameter or return types in objective c.

Comment: No, it is  not because of the naming.  And, no, a call site doesn't boil down just `getValue:`.  While you can't overload a method based on typing, that has nothing to do with the problem at hand which is simply a compiler crash.

Answer (score -5):

press these buttons in order - shift ⌘ K - that may work, what you named the class probably has little or nothing to do with it, which is why I recommend that you clean it, it's good for your program anyways it's kind of like giving a massage to your program relieving it's stress or in the computers case any data hang ups :D

Comment: Instead of immediately hitting Clean every time you have a problem, why not try to understand the problem so that you can know with certainty what fixes it and go straight to that solution any time you have the same problem in the future?